# Facebook and Gmail Sign-in using google firebase not working with safari browser

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have implemented **sign-in** by PopUp using  **google firebase** for facebook and gmail in the web-application.It works in all the browsers but doesn't work with `safari` browser and instead of redirecting to my application it goes directly to facebook timeline.

Do i need to do any special treatment for safari?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some issue with that particular safari browser so i cleared the cache and reset default settings for the browser and it worked.